# ATTRIBUTE_ACCESSORS Indicates an error indicating that the function definition was not found even though the macro was declared

Tags: unreal-engine5

Using Visual Studio. We would like to implement health and mana through the ATTRIBUTE_ACCESSORS macro in Unreal Engine 5. It is said that a macro can be defined and used to use ATTRIBUTE_ACCESSORS, but even though it is defined, an error occurs that there is no function definition in the line containing ATTRIBUTE_ACCESSORS(UAuraAttributeSet, Data).

```
// AttributeSet.h
// Copyright Min Creater

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "AttributeSet.h"
#include "AbilitySystemComponent.h"
#include "AuraAttributeSet.generated.h"

#define ATTRIBUTE_ACCESSORS(ClassName, PropertyName) \
    GAMEPLAYATTRIBUTE_PROPERTY_GETTER(ClassName, PropertyName) \
    GAMEPLAYATTRIBUTE_VALUE_GETTER(PropertyName) \
    GAMEPLAYATTRIBUTE_VALUE_SETTER(PropertyName) \
    GAMEPLAYATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INITTER(PropertyName)
/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class AURA_API UAuraAttributeSet : public UAttributeSet
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    UAuraAttributeSet(); //속성
    virtual void GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(TArray<FLifetimeProperty>& OutLifetimeProps) const override;

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, ReplicatedUsing = OnRep_Health, Category = "Vital Attributes")
    FGameplayAttributeData Health; //체력
    ATTRIBUTE_ACCESSORS(UAuraAttributeSet, Health);

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, ReplicatedUsing = OnRep_MaxHealth, Category = "Vital Attributes")
    FGameplayAttributeData MaxHealth;
    ATTRIBUTE_ACCESSORS(UAuraAttributeSet, MaxHealth);

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, ReplicatedUsing = OnRep_Mana, Category = "Vital Attributes")
    FGameplayAttributeData Mana; //마나
    ATTRIBUTE_ACCESSORS(UAuraAttributeSet, Mana);

    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, ReplicatedUsing = OnRep_MaxMana, Category = "Vital Attributes")
    FGameplayAttributeData MaxMana;
    ATTRIBUTE_ACCESSORS(UAuraAttributeSet, MaxMana);

    //BluepritnReadOnly - 엔진 내 블루프린트로 접근 

    /*
    * 새 속성을 추가하기 위한 단계.
    * 1. 변수 선언(OnRep_Health), 복제, 담당자 정의(UFUNCTION)
    * 2. 이를 정의하고 알림 매크로(cpp. GAMEPLAYATTRIBUTE_REPNOTIFY) 추가 
    * 3. 복제 변수를 추가하여(DOREPLIFETIME_CONDITION_NOTIFY, 조건 없음) 복제 값을 얻음
    * 
    * 이러한 모든 단계를 Attribute를 사용하고 추가하기 위한 상용구로 칭함. 
    * 속성이 필요한 모든 작업에는 이와 같은 상용구 단계를 따라야 한다. 
    */

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnRep_Health(const FGameplayAttributeData& OldHealth) const;

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnRep_MaxHealth(const FGameplayAttributeData& OldMaxHealth) const;

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnRep_Mana(const FGameplayAttributeData& OldMana) const;

    UFUNCTION()
    void OnRep_MaxMana(const FGameplayAttributeData& OldMaxMana) const;
};
```

```
// AttributeSet.cpp
// Copyright Min Creater


#include "AbilitySystem/AuraAttributeSet.h"
#include "Net/UnrealNetwork.h"



UAuraAttributeSet::UAuraAttributeSet()
{
    InitHealth(100.f);
    InitMaxHealth(100.f);
    InitMana(50.f);
    InitMaxMana(50.f);
}

void UAuraAttributeSet::GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(TArray<FLifetimeProperty>& OutLifetimeProps) const
{
    Super::GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(OutLifetimeProps);

    DOREPLIFETIME_CONDITION_NOTIFY(UAuraAttributeSet, Health, COND_None, REPNOTIFY_Always);
    DOREPLIFETIME_CONDITION_NOTIFY(UAuraAttributeSet, MaxHealth, COND_None, REPNOTIFY_Always);
    DOREPLIFETIME_CONDITION_NOTIFY(UAuraAttributeSet, Mana, COND_None, REPNOTIFY_Always);
    DOREPLIFETIME_CONDITION_NOTIFY(UAuraAttributeSet, MaxMana, COND_None, REPNOTIFY_Always);
    //복제하려는 모든 항목에 필요한 복제할 상태를 등록, 아무 조건 없이. 

}

void UAuraAttributeSet::OnRep_Health(const FGameplayAttributeData& OldHealth) const
{
    GAMEPLAYATTRIBUTE_REPNOTIFY(UAuraAttributeSet, Health, OldHealth);
}

void UAuraAttributeSet::OnRep_MaxHealth(const FGameplayAttributeData& OldMaxHealth) const
{
    GAMEPLAYATTRIBUTE_REPNOTIFY(UAuraAttributeSet, MaxHealth, OldMaxHealth);
}

void UAuraAttributeSet::OnRep_Mana(const FGameplayAttributeData& OldMana) const
{
    GAMEPLAYATTRIBUTE_REPNOTIFY(UAuraAttributeSet, Mana, OldMana);
}

void UAuraAttributeSet::OnRep_MaxMana(const FGameplayAttributeData& OldMaxMana) const
{
    GAMEPLAYATTRIBUTE_REPNOTIFY(UAuraAttributeSet, MaxMana, OldMaxMana);
}
```

```
// Build.cs
// Copyright Min Creater

using UnrealBuildTool;

public class Aura : ModuleRules
{
    public Aura(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)
    {
        PCHUsage = PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs;
    
        PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore", "EnhancedInput", "GameplayAbilities" });

        PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "GameplayTags", "GameplayTasks" , "NavigationSystem", "Niagara", "AIModule" });

        // Uncomment if you are using Slate UI
        // PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Slate", "SlateCore" });
        
        // Uncomment if you are using online features
        // PrivateDependencyModuleNames.Add("OnlineSubsystem");

        // To include OnlineSubsystemSteam, add it to the plugins section in your uproject file with the Enabled attribute set to true
    }
}
```

I rewrote build.cs, rewrote AttributeSet.h, and AttributeSet.cpp files, built it, regenerated the visual studio project, debugged it, and ran the engine in debug mode, but the engine stopped and crashed.